# VSTS Web Hooks get silently disabled?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

VSTS,

How does one configure VSTS to never auto-disable ServiceHooks that encounter errors? Looking thru the UI, there's no checkbox for 'always run, regardless of errors'.

Occasionally, we have to take-down the receiving service for maintenance, we need VSTS to continue to send the request regardless of any errors encountered (past or present).

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn’t the way to configure it to never auto disable service hooks that encounter errors.

Also, continue to send the request regardless of any errors encountered (past or present) will affect the performance.

You can build a app (e.g. windows service) to check and enable web hooks through REST API: [Update a subscription](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/hooks/subscriptions#update-a-subscription).

For example:

```
Put https://[account].visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/[subscription id]?api-version=1.0
```

Body (Content-Type:application/json)

```
{
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "eventType": "build.complete",
  "resourceVersion": "1.0-preview.1",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "scope":1,
  "status":0,
  "publisherInputs": {
    "buildStatus": "",
    "definitionName":"ClassTestVNext",
    "projectId": "578ca584-4268-4ba2-b579-7aaee499c306"
  },
  "consumerInputs":{"url":"http://XXXX/"}
}
```